# ROS and Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal working?

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, for testing of my previous question http://answers.ros.org/question/44632/ i wanted to test Ubuntu 12.10 and ROS.
Is it yet possible to use this combination?

With the installation sources

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

i get the error:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (= 1.6.5-s1347168835~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1348603799~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1347124102~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-filters (= 1.6.0-s1347133504~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1347181600~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1347172830~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.14-s1348597567~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.6-s1348605180~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1347170256~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.3-s1347133731~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1347128386~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1348603925~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1348606087~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1347124244~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.3-s1347133511~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (= 1.2.0-s1347122840~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1347141454~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common (= 1.8.0-s1347133482~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bond-core (= 1.6.3-s1347128144~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding (= 0.1.9-s1348595482~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (= 1.8.4-s1347128602~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1347122907~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-driver-common (= 1.4.0-s1347168681~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1347133680~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1347133988~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.4.2-s1347168414~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.2-s1348606011~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1347128571~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1347133837~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bullet (= 2.79-s1347124289~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-pluginlib (= 1.8.0-s1347128156~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1347128281~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1348599108~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1347141801~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.4-s1347171614~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1347122771~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common (= 1.8.0-s1347133548~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics (= 1.6.4-s1347133484~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1347180414~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and with changing it to:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu quantal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

apt-get cant find the ROS Packages.

When trying to build from source, it stops with

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte
-- +++ catkin
CMake Warning at catkin/cmake/tools/gtest.cmake:41 (message):
  GTest not found; C++ tests will fail to build.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/all.cmake:51 (include)
  catkin/CMakeLists.txt:12 (include)


TODO: implement add_roslaunch_check() in rostest-extras.cmake.
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on.
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~         traversing stacks/projects in dependency order         ~~
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ genmsg
-- +++ genpy
-- +++ gencpp
-- +++ genlisp
-- +++ rospack
-- Rospack building shared objects.
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
-- +++ std_msgs
-- std_msgs: 32 messages
-- +++ ros
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--    Making toplevel forward script for bash script rosrun
-- +++ roscpp_core
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   thread
-- +++ ros_comm
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- rosgraph_msgs: 2 messages
-- std_srvs: 0 messages
TODO: consider moving xmlrpcpp's headers into a subdirectory
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   regex
--   thread
CMake Error at ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/CMakeLists.txt:34 (message):
  Couldn't find log4cxx library


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So is the combination of Ubuntu 12.10 and ROS possible or am i doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44823/ros-and-ubuntu-12.10-quantal-working?/) by [sem](https://answers.ros.org/users/3265/sem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-09-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-09-30**:
apt-get should not be able to find any ROS packages as 12.10 is not supported.  The entries you added to your sources.list will not entirely work.  AFAIK you'll have to install from source.  The build error you are getting can likely be fixed with `sudo apt-get install liblog4cxx10-dev`

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-30**:
@jarvisshultz please make an answer out of your comment. It's the correct answer.

**Comment by [sem](https://answers.ros.org/users/3265/sem/) on 2012-09-30**:
installing of the liblog4cxx10-dev helped for this error, but now i am: Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)
but the bzip2 is already installed

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-01**:
For building from source, you will usually also need the -dev packages, not just the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.10 is not officially supported by ROS Fuerte (or any version of ROS).  Which means that you will have to install from source.  In order to compile ROS, your system will need many libraries that ROS is dependent on.  I mentioned `liblog4cxx10-dev` and @dornhege mentioned `libbz2-dev`. It seems that the [source install instructions for Ubuntu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) are a bit disorganized (IMO) the dependencies aren't really mentioned until section 1.7.  The [Debian source install page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian), for example, lists the dependencies right at the top of the page.

Regardless, installing all of the dependencies mentioned in either of these locations should help you continue on with the building process.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just finished installing ROS Fuerte from source on Ubuntu 12.10. Thought I should mention here. I basically followed the steps at:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

I kept hitting the same "library not found" errors from CMake, and simply kept installing them one by one using `apt-get`, including boost (1.49.0), log4cxx, etc. Finally, CMake configuration completed without any errors (there were a few deprecation warnings, though - they seemed harmless). `make` and `make` install worked fine without any trouble.

Further along the installation steps, we need to use `rosdep` to install some "system dependencies" (it internally calls `apt-get`, as far as I understand). This is where I ran into a bunch of errors, because certain packages were not defined for `quantal`, e.g.:

`image_view: No definition of [opencv2] for OS version [quantal]`

There were entries for `precise`, however (as revealed by `rosdep resolve opencv2`), and I stumbled upon an undocumented option "`--os`" here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/40081/rosdep-doesnt-recognize-os/

This worked for me, because I noticed that most of these package definitions referred to the same ROS package for multiple Ubuntu versions. From then on I passed in `--os=ubuntu:precise` to every `rosdep` call.

After this, `rosmake -a` is able to build almost all the ros packages. There was one recurring error amounting to Python not being able to locate module "`roslib.manifest`" that blocked a few packages from compiling, including any new packages that I wrote (from beginner tutorials, etc.). The solution to that was to find where the "`roslib`" directory (containing `manifest.py`) was located, and adding it to PYTHONPATH variable. On my system, I found it here:

`/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib-1.8.9-py2.7.egg/`

Note that `/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` was already in `PYTHONPATH`, but apparently nested directories are not checked (I don't know if there is a way to enable that, or if "`.egg`" directories are supposed to be expanded out in their parent - anyone care to shed some light on this?). At this point, `rosmake -a` is able to build all packages, and a more specific command like `rosmake <package-name>` also works. The ros nodes run as expected. Now, I noticed there are some other "`.egg`"s in dist-packages, and I may have to include them explicitly in `PYTHONPATH` in the future.

Also, I cannot confirm that the complete installation is stable, since I overrode the OS parameter (`--os=`) with `rosdep`, but I haven't bumped into any problems yet.

---

Originally posted by [napratin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3297/napratin/) with karma: 41 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4